# show part of html if session is equal item value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

I want some html codes to be visible to only admin and writer of that blog.
My session works in layout (i can show writer name on page) , and Admin part is working without problem. 
The problem is: the html part is not visible to the writer of the blog.

```
 @model IEnumerable<Myproject.Models.Blog>
  ...


 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {....

     @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
      {
        if (User.IsInRole("Admin") || @item.writer.name == @Session["name"])
                                        {

    // the html code...

                                        }
                                    }
    ...
    }
```

Comment: can you try this @item.writer.name == Session["name"] instead?

Comment: try removing any unnecessary `@` you can, probably both `@item` should be `item` and `@Session` should be `Session`, sometimes razor doesn't like it - alternatively if it's applicable you can try using [`ViewBag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag(v=vs.118).aspx) to store your info from your controller. It can sometimes be easier to store your values that way.

Comment: return is false

Comment: session is described in login controller, this page is another controller which lists blogs. Does it matter? – Edit: Thanks for help, passing session to the view as viewbag has solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok problem is fixed, I had to add the following line in the controller. And call that viewbag instead of the session.

```
ViewBag.user= Session["name"];
```